# Modules for hand-coded Typescript definition file

Tags: typescript

I'm using https://github.com/23/resumable.js in a Typescript project, and am trying to hand-code a type definition file for it as there isn't one on definitely typed. My first draft effort is at https://github.com/23/resumable.js/pull/264.

With this type definition file I can import resumable with something like:

```
import Resumable = require('../../lib/resumable')
```

I'm also using immutable.js in the project, and I can import properties from that as:

```
import {OrderedMap} from 'immutable'
```

In other words immutable is a module. I've tried various ways of declaring a module in the resumable type definition file, and I can get it to compile - for example with:

```
//.d.ts file
declare module 'resumable' {
    export class Resumable {...

//.ts file
import {Resumable} from 'resumable'
```

But then the app throws a run-time error about Resumable not being a function. As far as I can see the difference here is that resumable.js exports a constructor for Resumable objects, and Immutable (and jquery for example) exports a factory:

```
// Resumable
module.exports = Resumable; 

//Immutable
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ?    module.exports = factory() :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
      global.Immutable = factory()
}(this, function () {
```

Given the way resumable exports, is it possible to modify my type definition file to export it as a module?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can see the difference here is that resumable.js exports a constructor for Resumable objects,

The right thing to do is use `export =` and I see that that is exactly what you did anyways : https://github.com/matthewdenobrega/resumable.js/blob/008d0f1494f0a8e3ad96d4fac59b9ad9c96d6942/resumable.d.ts#L31